# SQL : Manipulate results to group them as collection

Tags: sql, subquery

I've got a very simple SQL question, but somehow i can't find a solution.

Doing a : `SELECT data from my_table` , returns something like :

```
ID  USER    HASH
1   1       e475defbdf98704c8e9fb0f284f17027
2   1       bcdfec888c034fc132320cfe58870e65
21  1       f84de50f5676ca240811c0bf298f1dea
23  2       d75fa60a30202cf3dfa0018f97cec705
24  2       8a7a3c6967ebd2499a7e4d73721e41fb
```

What i want, is an object like this one :

```
user_1 
    data_1
    data_2
    data_21
user_2 
    data_21
    data_23
    data_24
```

I don't know if it's doable with only sql.
Thanks ;)

Comment: `SELECT User, Hash FROM table ORDER BY user` And do not try to "cell merging" in SQL. It is a job for application layer.

Comment: you can also use group_concat if available and if you really must. but @lad2025 does have a point